# imap получение тела сообщения

Tags: pop3, php, imap

Добрый день. Есть функия которая при помощи imap по pop3 вытаскивает письма

```
function get_body($box = false, $num){  
        if($num > $this->get_count())
            return null;

        if(!$box)
            $box = $this->box;

        $struct = imap_fetchstructure($box,$num);
        if(!empty($struct->parts)){
            for($i = 0, $j = count($struct->parts); $i < $j; $i++){
                $part = $struct->parts[$i];
                if($part->subtype == 'PLAIN'){
                    $body = imap_fetchbody($box,$num, $i+1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            $body = imap_body($box,$num);

        return $body;
    }
```

как мне перевести тело сообщения к utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функции PHP для работы с utf-8 с помощью расширения XML:

```
utf8_encode(string); 
utf8_decode(utf8_string);
```

а ещё есть ф-ция для перекодировок строк других кодировок:

```
iconv('Имя_входной_кодировки','Имя_выходной_кодировки','строка_в_входной_кодировке');
```

например:

```
$win1251_str=iconv('KOI8-R','WINDOWS-1251',$koi8string);
```

Comment: Отлично сработала спайка   
iconv('koi8-r','UTF-8',base64_decode($body));  
но проблема с Англиским.
'dasdasdasdsd' => 'u╚jгZ╠ш' Страница на UTF-8